# Prove that for each cardinal number $\alpha > 0$ exists a topological space $X$ so that $ w(X) = \alpha$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that for each cardinal number $\alpha > 0$ exists a topological space $X$ so that $ w(X) = \alpha$, where $ w(X)$ is the minimal cardinality of all bases of the topology on X.

Can I just for each $\alpha > 0$ take a set with that cardinality and take discrete topology on the set?

Comment: What is $w(X)$? Is it the cardinal of the set of the connected components?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no, sorry I made it  clearer now

Comment: Yes, taking discrete topology on a set $X$ with $|X|=\alpha$ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the discrete topology works. Note that if $B$ is a basis for a discrete space $X$ then by definition every singleton $\{*\}$ can be written as union from $B$. This shows that $\{*\}\in B$. So every basis on a discrete space has to contain every singleton and therefore $|B|\geq |X|$.

On the other hand $B=\{\{x\}\ |\ x\in X\}$ is a basis for $X$. And $|B|=|X|$.

Combining these two observations we get that $w(X)=|X|$ and so your statement easily follows.